# How do I find the upper bound of a real number when $z$ has been restricted

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

From what I understand we manipulate the real number in question so that it takes the same format as a triangle inequality (whichever one it may be) and then we can use this to break up multiplications as moduli are multiplicative but I want to see this in action so that I can have a visual understanding of the process.

A question such as :

Give an upper bound for the real number

$|\frac{1}{z^2+1}|$ for any $z$ such that  $|z|=2$

or a more difficult example with polynomials on the numerator and denominator would be greately appreciated.

I have a particular question I want to solve but I don't want to post it because I want to use your advice to solve it myself.

Appreciated.

Comment: Can you state precisely what the mathematical question or problem that you are trying to answer? The expression "$|\frac{1}{z^2+1}| : |z|=2$" is not a question.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've just updated the question. They usually ask for "an upper bound for the real number" and they state the real number as a modulus fraction where the numerator and denominator are polynomials in terms of $z$ and then they restrict the $z$ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could proceed like this.

Because $\left| \frac{1}{z^2+1} \right| = \frac{1}{|z^2+1|}$, it follows that if $L$ is a lower bound for $|z^2+1|$ then $M = \frac{1}{L}$ is an upper bound for $\left| \frac{1}{z^2+1} \right|$.

So now we must find a lower bound for $|z^2+1|$.

The triangle inequality has the form $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$ which can be rewritten $|a| \ge |a+b| - |b|$. So the idea is to set up some triangle inequality where $|a| = |z^2+1|$.

Here's a way to do this:
$$|z^2| = |z^2 + 1 - 1| \le |z^2 + 1| + |-1| = |z^2+1| + 1
$$
and therefore, using that $|z|=2$, we obtain
$$|z^2 + 1| \ge |z^2| - 1 = |z|^2 - 1 = 2^2 - 1 = 3
$$
and so
$$\left| \frac{1}{z^2+1} \right| \le \frac{1}{3}
$$

**Added after the comment of @BrevanEllefsen:** Furthermore, upon substituting $z=2i$ this inequality becomes an equality, and therefore $\frac{1}{3}$ is the least upper bound of $\left|\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right|$ for $|z|=2$, in fact $\frac{1}{3}$ is the maximum value.

Comment: Worth noting we get equality when $z = 2i$ so we know this is the supremum

Comment: Thanks, I posted an addition to that effect.